# Почему тэг th:text не срабатывает

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

У меня есть следующий код admin.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Admin page</title>
</head>
<body>
    Dear <strong><p th:text="${name}"></p></strong>, Welcome to Admin Page.
    <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Код Spring-контроллера следующий:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, Model model) {

    try {
        securityService.autologin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getPassword());

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        model.addAttribute("name",authentication.getName());

        if (securityService.isAdmin(userForm.getUsername())) {
            return "redirect:/admin";
        }
    } catch (RestException e) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "User with username '"+userForm.getUsername()+"' not found");
    }

    return "redirect:/index";
}
```

Код Spring MVC-конфигурации следующий:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "ru.dev.avtonomki" })
public class WebMVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine(jspTemplateResolver()));
        resolver.setContentType("text/html");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setViewNames(ArrayUtil.array("*.jsp"));
        return resolver;
    }

    private TemplateEngine templateEngine(ITemplateResolver templateResolver) {
            SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
            engine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect(new GroupingStrategy()));
            engine.addDialect(new Java8TimeDialect());
            engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
            engine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(messageSource());
            return engine;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver jspTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        //resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addFormatter(new NameFormatter());
    }
}
```

Вопрос состоит в том, почему тэг `th:text` не срабатывает? В чем может быть причина этого?

Answer (score 0):

У меня впечатление, что присутствует путаница с .jsp и .html. TemplateResolver ищет файлы с .html (suffix), а ViewResolver смотрит на .jsp (viewNames) - вот они и не сходятся. То есть система вам разрешает путь к view на файл с расширением .jsp, но он не определяется как шаблон и не проходит обработку Thymeleaf. 
Непонятна необходимость использовать JSP при том, что Thymeleaf как раз на HTML5 рассчитан в первую очередь.